Options method not allowed - Node-Server with express.js
I generated a server stub with Swagger, added my business logic and now I got a problem.
When my frontend (Vue) sends a post request, I always get the message "OPTIONS method not allowed".
I can send the post data with curl, and everything works fine, but when the browser and my frontend tries it I always get the separate Options Request and the error that options method is not allowed.
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var cors = require('cors');
var serverPort = 8080;

// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
        exposeApi: true // This will enable separate handling of OPTIONS requests
    },
};

var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, 'api/openapi.yaml'), options);
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();

// Use CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

// Define a separate handler for OPTIONS requests
app.options('*', (req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.send();
});

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
});

Send a POST-Request to my API, and it didn't work because OPTIONS Method is not allowed

I wonder if you need to add some logging to see what the issue is. What happens if you send an OPTIONS method directly using cURL?

It feels that you need to pass cors() to the app.options too: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight
app.options('*', cors(), (req, res) => { ... });
